# Is the response phrased in a natural way to convey sarcasm?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Someone has behaved in an outrageous way at work. He meets in the next day.

**Coworker**: *How are you?*

**Person**: *I'm okay. I'm just a little embarrassed about my behavior yesterday.*

**Another coworker**: *Embarrassed? Why would you be embarrassed?*

**Coworker**: *Don't listen to him.*

Is "another coworker's" response phrased in a perfectly natural way to convey sarcasm?

Answer (score 1):

It does convey irony, but I am not sure about sarcasm, which is a bit more painful for the targeted person. I do not think that the following affirmation is groundless

[*Irony is to point out the absurdity of something. Sarcasm is meant to wound.*](https://archives.cjr.org/language_corner/language_corner_062314.php#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CIrony%20is%20to%20point%20out,Sarcasm%20is%20meant%20to%20wound.)

So it depends on the speaker's intention. You could emphasise sarcasm maybe by adding ***ever***:

> Embarrassed? Why would you **ever** be embarrassed?

or

> Embarrassed? ***Now*** why ***on earth*** would you be embarrassed? (***Makes me wonder...***)

Note that intonation plays a big role in how caustic irony or sarcasm can be.